# Disposing SQL objects inside another using block

Tags: c#

In one sql connection I have multiple sql commands and I wonder what approach is better - create and dispose SqlCommand for each operation or use only one sql command?

Eg:

```
using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(ConnectionString))
{
   connection.Open();

   using(SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("select...", connection))
   {
       cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

       cmd.CommandText = @"another query...";
       cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

       //and so on
   }
}
```

or

```
using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(ConnectionString))
{
   connection.Open();

   using(SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("select...", connection))
   {
       cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
   }

   using(SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("another query...", connection))
   {
       cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
   }
}
```

If SqlCommand(s) are inside another using block (in this cae SqlConnection), disposing will be done after close connection or immediately after running SqlCommand?

I'm asking because I have web api which receives a few hundred requests per minute and my goal is to optimize application for better garbage collector working - there might be memory leak

Comment: Are you asking whether it's okay to *reuse* a `SqlCommand` object for running a sequence of actual SQL commands? Because generally speaking, you should dispose the objects as soon as they are not used and both of your code snippets already do that. A bit confused...

Comment: This SO post explains that you can reuse the `SqlCommand` object. Just make sure you clean parameters of the command properly. When the entire sequence has finished execution, the code should dispose the `SqlCommand` (and probably, the `SqlConnection`) See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/670407/reusing-sqlcommand

Comment: @IgorSoloydenko Yes, it's about reusing, but I wonder how fast garbage collector will grab them in these cases

Comment: I have never seen a case where repetative create/dispose of anything is the most performance way of doing something given that being the only criteria. Your code appears to be synchronous and nothing seems to be declared static. So I would probably just declare the used objects and reuse them as has been mention be sure to do relevant closes and clean parameters.

Comment: Please see my answer below. The GC will do the job!

Comment: Wouldn't using an ORM like Entity Framework or Dapper be much easier?

Comment: @BCdotWEB it might be easier, but ORMs are slower than pure ado.net and I wan't to have full control of what I'm doing

Comment: @mkul Those performance differences are negligible, and you'll never have full control anyway. If I see ADO.NET code when doing a code review at work, that developer better have a seriously good reason for using it -- and a simple `SELECT` isn't one.

Comment: @BCdotWEB Negligible? I have read many articles that proves that EF is slower than ado.net (e.g. https://www.exceptionnotfound.net/dapper-vs-entity-framework-vs-ado-net-performance-benchmarking/). My question is generally about queries, not for only "simple SELECT"

Comment: @mkul I've been using EF for pretty everything and we have a lot of applications working with EF and I have only once had a performance problems with it... but then I just used `.AsNoTracking` it everything was fine again. On the other hand you can write super slow queries in pure SQL too. The only case where I couldn't use EF was when the schema of the table isn't known and the SQL is generated for the custom columns.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would create a SqlConnection for each SqlCommand, and wrap a function around each of them.

Assuming that in-between SqlCommands you would be doing some other work, the above approach would be a more efficient in acquiring and releasing the underlying pooled SQL connections, which are a scarce resource.

Further, placing each SqlConnection/SqlCommand in its own function follows the single responsibility principle and enables reuse.

A few hundred requests a minute would not place the GC under any major stress, with the overhead of creating the SqlConnection object.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can do this, and the garbage collector will do the job well. This is very close to your original code (snippet 1), but notice the parameter clear instructions.

```
using (var sqlConnection = new SqlConnection(ConnectionString))
{
   sqlConnection.Open();

   using (var command = new SqlCommand("select...", sqlConnection))
   {
       command.ExecuteNonQuery();
       command.Parameters.Clear();  // <-- IMPORTANT BEFORE RUNNING NEXT COMMAND

       command.CommandText = @"another query...";
       command.ExecuteNonQuery();
       command.Parameters.Clear();  // <-- IMPORTANT BEFORE RUNNING NEXT COMMAND

       // ...etc
   }
}
```